# Como obter o total de memória ocupada pela aplicação?

Tags: c#, .net, memória

Eu sei que existe o [`GC.GetTotalMemory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.gettotalmemory(v=vs.110).aspx), mas ele só mostra o consumo da memória gerenciada. Tem como descobrir o uso total da aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Teria que pegar o processo e mandar inspecioná-lo através da classe [`Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Conseguir identificar a memória usada é complicado. Existem basicamente duas medidas. Uma delas é a memória privada que só a aplicação está usando. Mas ela é enganosa porque não inclui a memória que está alocada por outros processos, inclusive do próprio sistema operacional, por causa da sua aplicação. Então pegar a memória privada não representa o exato consumo.

Mas se pegar a memória total de trabalho da aplicação, o que inclui toda memória que está vinculada à aplicação tem outro problema já que essa memória pode estar sendo usada por outras aplicações, então apesar de que essa quantidade memória estar sendo efetivamente usada, uma parte dela estaria sendo usada de qualquer forma mesmo que a aplicação não estivesse rodando e com aquela memória vinculada a ela.

```cs
    using static System.Console;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    
    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            using var proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            WriteLine(proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            WriteLine(proc.WorkingSet64);
        }
    }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/jimsAR). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p4gC0W). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/GetMemory.cs).

Note que o `using` é necessário para liberação do processo, caso contrário haverá vazamento de memória.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode utilizar

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process currentProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();

long memoryUsed = currentProc.PrivateMemorySize64;
```